# Conditional law of total probability

Tags: probability, self-learning, conditional-probability

Let $F_1, \dots, F_n$ be a partition of $\Omega$ the sample space. Let $E$ be an event. 
The law of total probability tells us:
\begin{align}
P(E) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(E\vert F_i) P(F_i)
\end{align}

Let's take now an other arbitrary event $B$, intuitively conditioning on this new event, we should have:
\begin{align}
P(E\vert B) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(E\vert F_i, B) P(F_i \vert B)
\end{align}

Here is my proof:

On the left hand side we have:
$$ P(E\vert B) = \frac{P(E \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
On the right hand side we have:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n P(E\vert F_i, B) P(F_i \vert B) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P(E\cap F_i \cap B) }{P(F_i \cap B)} \frac{P(F_i \cap B)}{ P(B)} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{P((E\cap B) \cap F_i)}{P(B)} \\
&= \frac{1}{P(B) }\sum_{i=1}^n P((E\cap B) \cap F_i)
\\ &= \frac{P(E\cap B)}{P(B)} \qquad \text{by the law of total probability}
\end{align}

Is my demonstration correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my demonstration correct?

Yes. It is.